# Google App Engine (NodeJS) errors under high load: Could not load the default credentials

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have a service running on **Google App Engine** which will receive a high amount of traffic in a few spikes around the day, going from around 10 requests per second to over 80 req/s for a few minutes.

During these spikes, we will see a number of `Could not load the default credentials` errors in our logs, and only during high load.

The errors are sometimes triggered by calls to Firestore:

```
at DocumentReference.get (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:207)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Other times related to Google Auth:

```
at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:174)
```

It seems like when the number of App Engine instances goes beyond a certain threshold, it has trouble keeping up.

Our app.yaml config:

```
runtime: nodejs14

instance_class: F2

automatic_scaling:
    min_instances: 1
    target_cpu_utilization: 0.8
    max_concurrent_requests: 50
```

Any thoughts or recommendations on how to avoid this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Credentials (OAuth Access Token) are valid for 3600 seconds. My guess is your code is requesting new credentials at a high rate. The metadata service is rate-limiting your service. 2) Rewrite your code to load the credentials in global namespace and then reuse those credentials when the method/function is invoked. This will reduce the rate the metadata server is hit with a credential request. The credentials will automatically refresh. 3) Edit your question to show your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example